# About save information from remote notification in ios

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, save, apple-push-notifications

I have a push notification with struct

```
{
    "aps":
    {
        "alert": "Hello, world!",
        "sound": "default",
        "funcId": "abc"  <-- this key i add more
    }
}
```

I want to store value of key **"funcId"** to use after app recives notification (app in state backgound or killed) like:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
   NSString *sFuncID = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"funcId"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:sFuncID forKey:Key_ID_notification];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

I had try use `NSUserDefaults` to store this value, but when app in state background and killed this value not store. 
**How to store vaule from remote notification to use when app relaunch?**

Thanks all support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to handle Push Notification in 2 different methods, so, you will have to save the value in 2 different methods. You will also need to make sure that the **userInfo** is **not nil** before saving the value/object into `NSUserDefaults`.

The code is something like below:-

```
//Receive Push Notification when the app is active in foreground or background
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
           didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

  if(userInfo){
   //TODO: Handle the userInfo here
    NSString *sFuncID = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"funcId"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:sFuncID forKey:Key_ID_notification];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   }

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Get the push notification when app is not open
    NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if(remoteNotif){
        [self handleRemoteNotification:application userInfo:remoteNotif];
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)handleRemoteNotification:(UIApplication*)application userInfo:(NSDictionary*)userInfo{

    if(userInfo){
   //TODO: Handle the userInfo here
    NSString *sFuncID = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"funcId"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:sFuncID forKey:Key_ID_notification];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but u way not success when my app in state background or killed

Comment: Please double check and use **setObject** instead of **setValue**. When the app is killed or in background, you will have to **Tap on the Notification** to go to the app in order to receive the notification. If you tap the app directly, you will not receive the notification info.

Comment: Thanks so much, i had know reason when i not recive notification info. So have another way to get notification info direct from tap to app?

Comment: No problem. Yes, when your app is not on foreground, the only way for the user to receive the notification is tap the notification to the app. If you tap directly on the app, you will not receive the notification.

Comment: Just trying to clean code a little here. Why call "handleRemote" in didFinishLaunching instead of calling the didReceiveRemote notification twice?
You have duplicated code here, this can't be right

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save to NSUserDefaults, since the you don't have the permission.

Create another file using NSFileManager, and set the proper file permission.

Then you'll be able to write to that file when receiving notification.

Comment: Thanks, but it will success when app run when app in background or killed it not

Comment: Checked out this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Protection_Values File Protection Values

Comment: You should set the file to be NSFileProtectionNone, so that even when the device is locked and a notification arrives, you can still write to that file

Comment: I know why my notification don't run. Because like @Ricky say: "you will have to Tap on the Notification to go to the app in order to receive the notification. If you tap the app directly, you will not receive the notification info". So thank u way. If u know way to get notification info with click direct app, plz show me. Thanks again.