# iOS - nsuserdefault reading old values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm saving and removing a dictionary on nsuserdefault.

Just saving and everything goes well.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler {
     NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:userInfo];
    [prefs setObject:stored forKey:key];
}
```

In a viewController

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [prefs objectForKey:key];
[prefs removeObjectForKey:key];
//I check here with debugger [prefs objectForKey:key] is returning nil
//doing stuff with data
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
OtherViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherViewController"];
controller.user = user;
[self parentShowViewController:controller sender:nil];
```

In OtherViewController viewDidLoad method:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [prefs objectForKey:key];
//Data has its old value and different to nil
//WHYY!!!!!!!
```

Tested on my iPhone 6S

## Update

I added [prefs synchronize] after save and before read, but still failing.

Comment: Consider that `viewDidLoad` could be called very soon in the life cycle of the app. Insert print lines to see in which order the code is executed. Try `viewWillAppear` which might be the more reliable solution.

Comment: I'm debugging the execution. The order is the expected.

Comment: Hm, if `data` is supposed to be `nil` when presenting the other view controller why do you retrieve the data from user defaults? Anyway `NSUserDefaults` should not be misused to store objects (con)temporarily.

Comment: if you are trying to pass data from 'viewController' to 'OtherViewController' you should look at 'prepareForSegue'

Comment: @vadian you are probably right. I'm using this as temporary store, but I don't understand why fails like this. I will change this approach. But i'm still in shock.

Comment: @Russell I'm not trying pass data between controllers. This is just a coincidence.

Comment: you are using `didReceiveRemoteNotification`  method only you need to also do same thing in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619259/about-save-in-formation-from-remote-notification-in-ios

Comment: @MikeAlter your are my new god

Comment: @Ricardo It is my duty !!! :D

Answer (score 0):

change your `ViewController code` as below.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [prefs objectForKey:key];
    [prefs removeObjectForKey:key];
    [prefs synchronize];
    //I check here with debugger [prefs objectForKey:key] is returning nil
    //doing stuff with data
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    OtherViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherViewController"];
    controller.user = user;
    [self parentShowViewController:controller sender:nil];
```

Comment: I added [prefs synchronize] after save and before read, but still failing.